OMPython: How to dynamically modify simulation parameters?
Here is my need: I use OMPython to solve a model with given inputs. Then, I want to modify the model and simulation parameters (for example to perform sensitivity analysis) using some intermediate paramaters. I tried to use setParameter and setSimulationOptions to do so:
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
param1 = 25
param2 = 1e-3
mod = ModelicaSystem(model_path + "SuperModel.mo", "SuperModel")
mod.setParameters("initialTemperature = param1")
mod.setSimulationOptions("tolerance=param2")
mod.simulate()

When doing that, I get:
mod.getParameters()
    'initialTemperature' : 'param1'

mod.getSimulationOptions()
    {'startTime'...,
    'tolerance' = 'param2'}

In other words, the name is passed but not the value.
Is there a way to do it properly? is OMPython the good candidate for that?
I started to dig into ExternData library to use instead a *.csv file to set the parameters from the OpenModelica model instead, but it implies many writtings from the Python main code, and readings from OM model, does not feel efficient at all!
Any suggestions are very welcome, thx!

Have you tried using f-strings? ex. f"initialTemperature = {param1}"

Thank you steeldriver, the f-string did the trick!
I was thinking the wrong way, I thought the OMPython function was sending directly the inputs to modelica...
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
param1 = 25
param2 = 1e-3
mod = ModelicaSystem(model_path + "SuperModel.mo", "SuperModel")
mod.setParameters(f"initialTemperature = {param1}")
mod.setSimulationOptions(f"tolerance = {param2}")

mod.getParameters()
    'initialTemperature' : '25'

mod.getSimulationOptions()
    {'startTime'...,
    'tolerance' = '1e-3'}

